# How to know the length of JSON array via IConfiguration?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I have a `secret.json` as follows. I use Secret Manager tools to show the `secret.json`.

```
{

  "Users": [
    {
      "UserName": "xxx@yyy.zzz",
      "Email": "xxx@yyy.zzz",
      "Password": "$aA12345"        
    },
    {
      "UserName": "aaa@bbb.ccc",
      "Email": "aaa@bbb.cc",
      "Password": "$aA12345"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the `Seed.Initialize` I want to use the length of array `Todos` obtained on the fly rather than the hard code one.

```
public static class Seed
{
    public static void Initialize(IConfiguration configuration, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();


        if(!userManager.Users.Any())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = configuration[$"Users:{i}:Username"],
                    Email = configuration[$"Users:{i}:Email"]
                };
                userManager.CreateAsync(user, configuration[$"Users:{i}:Password"]).Wait();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

## Question

How to obtain the length of JSON array with `IConfiguration`? In other words, I want to write something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < configuration["Users"].Blablabla(); i++)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a class that matches your structure like:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public TodoItem[] Todos { get; set; }
}

public class TodoItem
{
    public string Todo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
}
```

And then get it as a strongly-typed array:

```
User[] users = configuration.GetSection("Users").Get<User[]>();
```

You can probably figure out how to make the loop with this :)

Comment: So you mean the user has todos e.g. `"Users":[{"UserName":"a", "Todos":[{}]]`?

Comment: Added that as an example too. It just happens that that format works for DateTime.

Comment: Funnily, no. The TodoItem in the array will be null.